# What are the accessibility problems of Qt?

Tags: unity-2d, qt, accessibility

Jonathan Ridell said in a [blog post](http://kamikazow.wordpress.com/2011/01/14/so-canonical-ported-unity-to-qt%E2%80%A6/#comment-578) that there were accessibility problems with Qt. I would just like to know what those problems are. Thank you very much and keep up the excelent work. Ubuntu Rocks!

Answer (score 3):

I haven't done any development in Qt, but my gloss on the subject of accessibility there is that the concern might be a bit overblown.  My understanding is that while GTK has built-in ATK support, Qt has to use a 'bridge' component to tie its native system to the accepted Linux accessibility framework.

Update -- I might have been premature in calling this issue overblown.  For instance, as user9237 says, it doesn't look like AT-SPI was really ever implemented.  So the trolltech doc quoted looks to be a bit "optimistic" .
Here is an interesting blog post, unfortunately still a bit old, covering a lot of these issues : [Qt/KDE and the state of free accessibility](http://jpwhiting.blogspot.com/2010/02/state-of-free-accessibility.html).

Here's Mark Doffman's [code site for Qt AT-SPI](http://gitorious.org/qt-at-spi).  Of which he says,

> This project is a Qt plugin that
>   bridges the QAccessible API’s to the
>   AT-SPI 2 protocol enabling Qt
>   applications to be used with Orca,
>   Accerciser, and GOK.

The possibly bogus Trolltech/Nokia link:

> Here's what Qt docs say about Qt
>   accessibility (from
>   [trolltech/nokia](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/accessible.html)):
>
> > Accessibility support in Qt consists of a generic interface, implemented
> >     for a technology >on each platform:
> >     MSAA on Windows, Mac OS X
> >     accessibility on the Mac, and Unix/X11
> >     AT-SPI >on Linux. Qt's accessibility
> >     interface closely follows the MSAA
> >     (Microsoft Active >Accessibility)
> >     standard, which most clients support.
> >     Other technologies used by Qt >provide
> >     similar functionality.*

A slightly newer [document](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/accessible.html) gives an overview of Qt accessibility.

By contrast, here's [a quick run-down on accessibility interfaces](http://library.gnome.org/devel/accessibility-devel-guide/stable/dev-start-5.html.en)  from the Gnome project:
GAIL (GNOME Accessibility Implementation Library) is an implementation of the accessibility interfaces defined by ATK. GTK is a toolkit which is already mapped to ATK by the GAIL module. License, download and other information can be found [here](http://www.t2-project.org/packages/gail.html). The [GAIL source code](ftp://ftp.gnome.org/pub/GNOME/sources/gail/) also serves as an excellent tutorial for advanced ATK usage. In addition, you may be interested in the [GAIL Reference Manual](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gail-libgail-util/stable/).

Answer (score 2):

The quote in the first answer seems incorrect http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/accessible.html

"Qt supports Microsoft Active Accessibility (MSAA) on Windows and Mac OS X Accessibility on Mac OS X. On Unix/X11, support is preliminary."

AT-SPI support was never implemented for Qt on Linux (because it would require writing CORBA bindings).  dbus AT-SPI is now available and could be implemented if someone had the time, sadly nobody has so far.

Answer (score 1):

Accessibility on Linux used to be a problem for Qt due to the AT-SPI support requiring CORBA.

This is now fixed: starting with Ubuntu 11.10, Qt comes with accessibility support based on the dbus AT-SPI. Accessibility is available for classic QWidget-based applications as well as QML applications.